# Debian Wheezy GNOME corrupted after reboot

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, display

I have a Debian 32 bit machine running a server application.
During previous reboot there seems to be some problem with display manager.

After boot the display is blank. I am able to SSH to this from other systems and have root access. During boot the display works fine.

Can you please tell me how can I reinstall GNOME or display manager or reset these display settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont,t know what display-manager you use, So this will reinstall your Display-manager and  gnome.  `apt install --reinstall $(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager | cut -d / -f 4) gnome-session`